# Coinbase API spot, buy and sell price for different currencies

Tags: swift, coinbase-api

I'm using Coinbase API to currently get the spot, buy and sell price of Bitcoin. I added a picker view with all the supported currencies and when I change the currency the spot price changes but for the buy and sell price it doesn't. Here is my code, not sure why isn't working...

```
@IBOutlet weak var btcSpotPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btcBuyPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btcSellPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedCurrency: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var currencyPicker: UIPickerView!
var currencies: [CoinbaseCurrency]?

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    self.selectedCurrency.setTitle(currencies?[row].iso, for: .normal)
    getSpotPrice()
    getBuyPrice()
    getSellPrice()
}

func getSpotPrice()
{
    Coinbase().getSpotRate(withCurrency: self.selectedCurrency.currentTitle) { (spotPrice: CoinbaseBalance?, error: Error?) in
        if let error = error
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
            alert.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            self.btcSpotPrice.text = spotPrice!.amount! + " " + spotPrice!.currency!
        }
    }
}

func getBuyPrice()
{
    Coinbase().getBuyPrice(withQuantity: "1", currency: "GBP") { (btc: CoinbaseBalance?, fees: [Any]?, subtotal: CoinbaseBalance?, total: CoinbaseBalance?, error: Error?) in

        if let error = error
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
            alert.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            self.btcBuyPrice.text = total!.currency!
        }
    }
}

func getSellPrice()
{
    Coinbase().getSellPrice(withQuantity: "1", currency: self.selectedCurrency.currentTitle) { (btc: CoinbaseBalance?, fees: [Any]?, subtotal: CoinbaseBalance?, total: CoinbaseBalance?, error: Error?) in

        if let error = error
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
            alert.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            self.btcSellPrice.text = total!.amount!
        }
    }
}
```

On my getBuyPrice method, even hardcoding the currency to "GBP" British Pound the btcBuyPrice label still shows USD. It works perfectly for the spotPrice method but not for the buy and sell price.